# How to traverse git repository at the lower level (than git log)

Tags: git

wanted to get to know how to go through list of all commits (or all from single branch) in git. How does `git log` do this (pointers to part of codes would be cool too, I just don't really know where to start)? Can I do it on raw filesystem somehow?

Reasoning is: need to write tool in other language that doesn't need to call system command.

UPDATE: I've read [Git internals: Git objects](http://git-scm.com/book/ch9-2.html) (and following chapters), I do understand that there are also packfiles. Main problem I have is to understand what's going on when we run: `git rev-list --all`. Or - for single branch - same command without `--all` flag. Is git figures out the head, pulls it from it's object store, checks for parents' shas, pulls those from object store and so one? Or is there some other, faster method?

Comment: Read http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals, especially http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you have already come across this:
***LibGit2*** : https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2

> libgit2 is a portable, pure C implementation of the Git core methods
>   provided as a re-entrant linkable library with a solid API, allowing
>   you to write native speed custom Git applications in any language with
>   bindings.

Its an open source, browsing through the code, should give you some valuable inputs..
E.g: [Commit.c](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/development/src/commit.c)

Answer (score 0):

The branches are mere files in a `.git/refs` folder, each file contains a sha1 for a current branch tip. Also, after `git gc` all refs could be collected in the `.git/packed-refs` file.